# Need to print a string after some assigning. But output is Blank. What is the mistake?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, operators

I need to print "ac" as output. But it is not printing anything. What is the mistake?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    x[0]='a';
    x[1]='c';
    x[2]='\0';
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x[0] = 'a';` -- Change that to `x.at(0) = 'a';` and you will get your answer.

Comment: or pointing you in the same direction in a different way: how many characters are there in an empty string?

Comment: The square bracket operator doesn't allocate space. Accessing elements after the allocated space is undefined.

Comment: Also, you seem to be confusing null-terminated char arrays with `std::string`.  A `std::string` does not require you to put a `\0` at the end of it.

Answer (score 3):

The program has undefined behavior because you may not use the subscript operator to assign values to an empty string.

Also the assignment of the zero character is redundant.

```
x[2]='\0';
```

Starting from the C++ 11 the terminating zero is automatically appended to objects of the type `std::string`.
For example this code snippet

```
string x;

std::cout << static_cast<int>( x[x.size()] ) << '\n';
```

is valid and `0` will be outputted.

You could write instead

```
string x;

x += 'a'; // it is the same as x.push_back( 'a' );
x += 'c';

cout<<x<<endl;
```

Or you could just initialize the string like

```
string x = { 'a', 'c' };
```

or use the assignment

```
string x;
x = { 'a', 'c' };
```

If you want to use the subscript operator then you have to create a string with the required number of elements like

```
string x( 2, ' ' );
x[0] = 'a';
x[1] = 'c';
cout<<x<<endl;
```

Comment: Why did you write that so complicated?

Comment: @user11914177 I see nothing complicated.

Comment: "The program has undefined behavior because you may not use the subscript operator to assign values to an empty string" is probably the most complicated way to say that the string has no components allocated.

Comment: It is worth to say, that the ```\0``` is used, but is automatically added.

Comment: "the string has no components allocated" is indeed simpler, but it is also incomplete -- it's fails to state that the [] operator won't allocate space (and that using the [] to access elements beyond the allocated space is undefined behavior).

Comment: I didn't know `x[x.size()]` was valid. Though `x.at(s.size())` still throws.

Comment: *I didn't know x[x.size()] was valid* -- The `x.at(x.size())` should still throw, since you are corrupting the string's housekeeping mechanism and all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

The string `x` has a size of zero at initialization. Meaning there are no components that are stored by the string. Setting components that don't exist obviously is not working, also this isn't adding a new element.

You can use the `push_back`function to add elements to your string.